# clion cmake project not compiling: dyld mach-o, but built for simulator (not macOS)

Tags: c++, macos, clion

I'm trying to build a C++ project using Clion and I get the following message in the console.

dyld: mach-o, but built for simulator (not macOS). If I try with debugger I get a failed to build target message.

It's worth noting that I started this project using clion on Windows and all the code compiles just fine on that OS. I'm guess this has to do with some gcc macOS issue and I'm not really sure.

Here is what is in my cmake.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(Fractal_Creator)

if(APPLE)
    set(CCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
else()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
endif()


set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp BitmapFileHeader.h BitmapInfoHeader.h)
add_executable(Fractal_Creator ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: Do you have some leftover build files in the same directory? It looks like the linker is picking up something that was created previously, and to be run on the iOS Simulator.

Comment: I tried deleting my debug directory and importing from source to clion to see if maybe that would fix things and I still get the same error.

Comment: Do you have flags like CC, CXX, CFLAGS, etc. set somewhere in your shell configuration?

Comment: good question @skalarproduktraum  ... are you talking about places like my .bash_profile ?

Comment: Yes, .bash_profile, .bashrc, etc. or .zshrc if using ZSH.

Comment: I think you also have a typo in the CMake file, on line 5... should be `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, not `CCMAKE_...`.

Comment: @skalarproduktraum the typo was the problem! ... it works now!

Comment: That is... weird. Let me put this as an actual answer, so you can close the whole thing. Happy it worked!

Comment: Sounds good! thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

On line 5, you have `CCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, which should be `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. As written in the comments above, this seems to fix the problem.